# Return tinyint value as predefied text in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to return the value of a tinyint column as a predefined text.

In my dB, I have a column called thing_status which is a tinyint. The values are 0='Empty', 1='Full' and 2='Removed'.

When I do my query, I would like to add an extra entry that contains the text representation of thing_status.

For example:

```
SELECT
   thing_id,
   thing_status,
   {function to convert status to string} AS thing_status_text
```

I had 2 ideas already, but neither seemed a good fit:

1. I could use IF THEN statements, but the actual lists of status texts is about 6 items, so the statement would be quite ugly and nasty to work with.
2. I could create another table with the statuses. But it seems to me that if this can be done IN the query, then it would be more efficient. Plus another table for 6 things that need to only be used once seems like overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case statement:

```
select thing_id, thing_status,
       (case when thing_status = 0 then 'Empty'
             when thing_status = 1 then 'Full'
             when thing_status = 2 then 'Removed'
       end) as thing_status_text
```

You can also put this into a view, so it is available to any query that wants to use it.

However, you might also be interested in `enum`, a data type helpful in this situation.

Comment: Thanks. How would I put the text into thing_status_text. Because I still need the raw value as well.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss . . . You might be interested in the enum type (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html).

Comment: I am reading about ENUM. However, I am having a problem finding an example of how to choose the correct text to match thing_status. I have created a new column of ENUM type and entered the appropriate texts. Would one of you be kind enough to show me the correct query format to match the text with the value of thing_status and return it as thing_status_text(or, the original column name which is thing_status_texts)

Comment: @LeeLoftiss . . . The enum would be instead of the numeric status.  However, you might want to pose a new question asking about the best representation for such a variable (be sure to explain how you want to use it).

Comment: Thanks. For your answer above, could you add how to put those strings into thing_status_text? I think it is a good answer and I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using the `ELT()` operator:

```
SELECT 
thing_id,
thing_status, 
ELT(thing_status, 'Empty', 'Full', 'Removed') AS thing_status_text;
```